# how to show the exception window in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, debugging, exception, visual-studio-2019

My situation is this,

I am running an application in debug,
an exception happens so VS breaks and shows me a little window with exception information,
I click on `view details` and a new window appears with more useless information,
I close this new window,

now my original exception window is gone, how do I get it back ?
I googled this but don't know the exact phrase to use in google to get correct results

**EDIT**

I mean this window, when this window is gone how do you get it back ?

[image]

Comment: Menu Debug/Windows/Exception Settings?

Comment: @KungPhoo That is not the window  I mean, I mean the small window that shows in VS when you are debugging and an exception occured

Comment: Clicking on the `X` that marks the exception? -- What version of VS do you have? When you open the details Window, the other pane should not close.

Comment: @Jimi I have Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.11.9 Well that "pane" did close with me for some dark reason and I could not get it back. I never tried to click on the `X` because I always was afraid that this would happen

Comment: The `X` means the white `X` on red background. Clicking it opens up the exception *pane* (it's a [HwndWrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.platformui.hwndwrapper) that holds a custom Window). -- When you open the Exception Details Popup Dialog (Quick Watch), that pane doesn't close. Usually. Maybe you have some active VS extensions? E.g., a third-party debugger visualizer.

Comment: @Jimi The only extensions I have are DevExpress and VisualSVN, I once had CodeRush but disabled it because it slowed down VS to much. I never clicked on either of the 2 `X` that you can see on my screenshot

Comment: I was able to get the exception message in C++ by using the menu item View→Other Windows→Stack Trace Explorer. I don't know if it is the same for C#. It's not quite the same dialog as I had before I clicked the X, though.